# How to make Typescript and Knockout.js working with MVC application

Tags: typescript, model-view-controller, knockout.js

Binding a knockout .js viewModel to MVC problem.

I have tried to follow at least 5 tutorials and all of them look different from each other, nothing worked for me. I dont get any errors while building the app.

TS file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

export module HopCRM {
    export class ContactViewModel {
        text: string = "Test";
        public test: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        console.log("hello")
        this.test = ko.observable("Test testing testing")

    }             
}

}
```

My CSHTML:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: test">Waiting for viewModel</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/Typescript/ContactViewModel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1        /jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;
    (function () {
        viewModel = new HopCRM.ContactViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);  
    });
</script>
```

I expect a binding from public test or at least simple console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use export and modules it's needed to use webpack. 
If you don't need such complexity then try to use just classes without any export/imports:

**Your ts file:**

```
class ContactViewModel {
        text: string = "Test";
        public test: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        console.log("hello")
        this.test = ko.observable("Test testing testing")

    }             
}
```

**Usage(in cshtml):**

```
const viewModel = new ContactViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See my working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/dgnyspwa/3/

Comment: I get as far as console log, but now I get ReferanceError: ko is not defined.

Comment: Was your knockout script loaded successfully? Could you call `console.log(ko);` before doing anything else?

Comment: That seems to be the problem - ko is not defined. Would itbe my reference patch?

Comment: You're calling ko.applyBindings from your view, not from the ts file, right?

Comment: I was, now I used a code from your answer. I commented out ko.applyBinding from view.

EDIT:

okay, It was my fault, I fallowed your answer again and put ko.binding in cshtml instead of ts file, and everything works great! Thank you

Comment: You still should call `ko.applyBindings` from your view, I've updated my answer